# How to use the $b\cdot\nabla$ operator?

Tags: proof-verification, vector-analysis, vector-fields

While trying to prove

> $$[c\cdot (b\cdot\nabla) - b\cdot(c\cdot\nabla)]a = (\nabla\times a) \cdot (b\times c)$$

I had some difficulties on how to treat the term $(b\cdot\nabla)$.
It seems that $(b\cdot\nabla)$ is an operator.
But how to use it? And also any one can help in prooving the above formula?

Comment: $$(b\cdot \nabla)a = (b_1\partial_1 + b_2\partial_2 + b_3\partial_3)a$$ I don't know of an elegant proof of the main result. But you can at a minimum grind it out in 123 (or xyz) coordinates. If you know them, the $\epsilon, \delta$ notation and Einstein summation conventions would help write that in somewhat compact form.

Comment: Could you explain what the $\partial$s mean in the definition, @SimonS?

Comment: Compact notation for partial derivatives: $\partial_1 = \partial/\partial x_1$, etc.

Comment: May I ask what kind of output we have for $\left( b \cdot \nabla \right)a$? It seems like you're multiplying the $a$ by the dot product to its left like real numbers, @SimonS.

Comment: Do you know how to work with components, i.e. writing $a= \sum a_i e_i$ where $e_i$ are basic-vectors and how the expressions for $a\cdot b$ and $a\times b$ reads in this formulation?

Comment: Yep, I'm aware of how they read, but the multiplication in the first comment's RHS is confusing, @Winther.

Comment: OK, using this it follows that the operator you have trouble with can be written $b\cdot \nabla = \sum_{i=1}^n b_i e_i \cdot \sum_{j=1}^n e_j \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} = \sum_{i=1}^n b_i \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$. 
When this acts on a vector $a$ it produces the vector $[b\cdot \nabla]a = \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n b_i \frac{\partial a_j}{\partial x_i} e_j$.

Comment: ^ Winther beat me to it (with $n = 3$ here)

Comment: Oh, gotcha. It was kinda confusing to not see parentheses around the vector $a$. Thanks, @Winther.

Comment: May I ask what the $(\nabla \times a)$ means on the right hand side? It seems like it isn't acting on anything. How can one perform the cross product operation between an operator and a vector? :-/

Comment: Do you know about the [Levi-Civita symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol#Three_dimensions) $\epsilon$? Using this we can write the components of the vector $a\times b$ (here for $n=3$) as $(a\times b)_i = \sum_{j=1}^3\sum_{k=1}^3\epsilon_{ijk} a^jb^k$ so $a\times b = \sum_{i=1}^3 (a\times b)_i e_i$.

Comment: Are the vectors you are dealing with $3$D vectors? In that case it is probably most easy to work directly with [the definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Coordinate_notation) $a\times b = (a_2b_3-a_3b_2)e_1 + (a_3b_1-a_1b_3)e_2 + (a_1b_2-a_2b_1)e_3$ instead of the more abstract and general form I mentioned above.

Comment: (I didn't ask the question btw! I kinda crashed the party because I was curious as I'd not seen such notation before!) Thank you for the help though!

Comment: @Khallil Hehe, I did not notice:) Anyway it might be useful for OP.

Comment: (∇×a ) is defined to be curl of a and expressed exactlay as @Winther said

Comment: What you mean by the word "btw" @Khallil

Comment: (Sorry, I have a bad habit of abbreviating. It stands for "by the way", @israasharbeh.)

Comment: nice to learn abbreviations like this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $e_1,e_2,e_3$ be your (orthonormal) basis vectors so that any vector $x = (x_1,x_2,x_3)$ can be written $x  = x_1e_1 + x_2e_2 + x_3e_3$. The basis vectors, usually $e_1=(1,0,0)$, $e_2=(0,1,0)$ and $e_3=(0,0,1)$ satisfy $e_i \cdot e_j = 0$ if $i\not=j$ and $e_i\cdot e_i = 1$. Using this we have that the operator $b\cdot\nabla$ can be written

$$b\cdot \nabla = (b_1e_1+b_2e_2+b_3e_3)\cdot\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1} e_1+\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1} e_2+\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1} e_3\right) \\= b_1\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1} + b_2\frac{\partial}{\partial x_2} + b_3\frac{\partial}{\partial x_3}$$

which is a scalar operator (in other words it is not a vector itself). When this operator acts on a vector $a= a_1 e_1 + a_2 e_2 + a_3e_3$ then the result is a vector

$$[b\cdot \nabla]a = \left(b_1\frac{\partial a_1}{\partial x_1} + b_2\frac{\partial a_1}{\partial x_2} + b_3\frac{\partial a_1}{\partial x_3}\right)e_1 \\ + \left(b_1\frac{\partial a_2}{\partial x_1} + b_2\frac{\partial a_2}{\partial x_2} + b_3\frac{\partial a_2}{\partial x_3}\right)e_2+\left(b_1\frac{\partial a_3}{\partial x_1} + b_2\frac{\partial a_3}{\partial x_2} + b_3\frac{\partial a_3}{\partial x_3}\right)e_3$$

In more compact form the $i$'th component can be written

$$([b\cdot \nabla]a)_i = b_1\frac{\partial a_i}{\partial x_1} + b_2\frac{\partial a_i}{\partial x_2} + b_3\frac{\partial a_i}{\partial x_3}$$

or even more compact by using a sum $([b\cdot \nabla]a)_i = \sum_{j=1}^3b_j \frac{\partial a_i}{\partial x_j}$.

---

To prove the formula you can simply write out both the left and right hand side of the equation in terms of the components of $a,b,c$ and compare the two expressions (which should be equal for any value of the components of $a,b,c$).

Comment: even more compact $b_i\partial_ia_j$